# Lilypond first alternative has only one note

Tags: lilypond, repeats

I have used repeats with alternatives before without any problem, but now (all of a sudden?) I am seeing some very odd behavior, where the first alternative only has one note regardless of duration. Here is a very simple example:

This:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\relative c' {
  \repeat volta 2 { c4 c c c |}
  \alternative { d d d d |} {e e e e |}
}
```

Renders this:

[image: score snippet]

And, incidentally, I get a barcheck error at the end of the second alternative.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. I am baffled!

Answer (score 12):

Doh.

I omitted the outer curly braces around the two alternatives. The corrected version should be:

```
\relative c' {
  \key f \major
  \repeat volta 2 { c4 c c c |}
  \alternative { { d d d d |} {e e e e |} }
}
```

Comment: Is this intended as "edit" to the question above? It is different from the graphics at least...

Comment: @guidot it's not an "edit" to the question, it's the *answer* to the question. The OP forgot that you need a set of curly braces round *all* the "alternative" options. The incorrect input in the question gives the warning message  "More alternatives than repeats.  Junking excess alternatives." It is actually defining *four* alternative endings, each one note long (the four d's), and the curly braces round the four e's are just irrelevant noise (but not an error, as such).

Comment: Tomorrow, you can accept your own answer so the system marks this as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message because of a different error:

```
\new Staff\relative c'' {
  \clef treble \key bes \major \time 3/4
  \repeat volta 2 { a c a f c e | }             
  \alternative {
    { f4. g16 a bes a bes c } |
    { f,2. } |
  }
}
```

-> "More alternatives than repeats. Junking excess alternatives."

Should be:

```
  \alternative {
    { f4. g16 a bes a bes c |}
    { f,2. |}
  }
```